# Segmentation fault in parsing code

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

I have this code that extracts strings between two specified strings specifically `<title>` and `</title>`. But when I run the program, I get `Segmentation Fault: 11` Any solutions?

```
int main(){

        struct stat st;
        stat("test.txt", &st);
        int size = st.st_size;
        printf("%d\n", size);
        FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "rb");

        char *bytes = (char*)malloc(size);        
        fread(bytes,size,1,f);
        fclose(f);
        parser(bytes);
        return 0;
}

void parser(char *bytes){
        struct stat st;
        stat(bytes, &st);
        int size = st.st_size;
        char *output = (char*)malloc(size);
        char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "<title>");
        char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "</title>");
        if(ptr2){
            strncpy(output, ptr+7, (ptr2 - (ptr+7)));
            puts(output);
            free(output);
            parser(ptr2);
        }
        free(bytes);
        free(output);

}
```

Comment: You are testing the size of 'yeah.txt' but then opening 'test.txt'?

Comment: Because you `stat` the contents of the file instead of a filename in `parser`? Your char buffer `bytes` as well as `output` aren't null-terminated, which is required for the functions in `<string.h>`, e.g. `strstr`.

Comment: @narb Sorry it's supposed to be 'test.txt' instead of 'yeah.txt'

Comment: @MiguelLorenzoPanagsagan: Pro tip: Use a variable for the file name instead of hard-coding it on each occurrence, so that you have to maintain it only in one place.

Comment: It's just a simple txt file. `Hello <title>Hello</title> <title>Hi</title> hello <title>hello</title>`

Comment: @MOehm The "hello" "hi" "hello" actually are outputted. But the error occurs after the output.

Comment: You allocate your `output` according to the `size` you get from your meaningless `stat`. (In parser, you operate on a char buffer. The fact that it comes from a file is irrelevant.) You should allocate the buffer according to the length of the title, which you can calculate from the results from `strstr`. (Both of which can be null, which you should check on both.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here.

In no particular order:

- you're double-freeing `output` (in the case where you find a string). That's highly likely to provoke a segfault, although not necessarily at the point of the second call to `free`. You're also freeing `bytes` even when it is not the address which was returned from `malloc` (in the recursive call to parse). That will also cause problems, and it is bad design: functions should normally not free strings which are passed to them as arguments.
- In parser, you are calling `stat` on the contents of the file, not on the filename. That will generally fail, and `size` will be meaningless. That's particularly egregious since you don't actually need the size.
- you probably don't want to use `strncpy`. `strncpy` does not null-terminate the copy unless a NUL is found in the original. So you end up with an unterminated copy, which might cause all sorts of havoc.

  Instead, just use `memcpy` (which also doesn't null-terminate, but at least it doesn't fool you into thinking that it might) and add the NUL yourself.
- The string you initially read from the file is not NUL-terminated. So `strstr` will keep reading beyond the end of the string.
- `parser` is recursive and not tail-recursive. It could easily be written to be tail recursive, and your C compiler might be able to apply TCO in that case, but as written it has the potential to build up a large call stack.
- `parser` does not verify that the first `strstr` found a string before calling `strstr` on the result. So when there are no more `<title>` to find, you'll call `ptr2 = strstr(NULL, "</title>");`. That will certainly segfault.

Here's some code which might help:

```
/* Forward declare parser */
void parser(char *bytes);

int main(){
        struct stat st;
        stat("test.txt", &st);
        /* CHECK RETURN VALUE */
        int size = st.st_size;
        printf("%d\n", size);
        FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
        /* CHANGE: need space for the NUL */
        char *bytes = malloc(size + 1);        
        size_t nread = fread(bytes,size,1,f);
        if (nread != size) { /* HANDLE ERROR */ }
        /* CHANGE: NUL terminate string */
        bytes[nread] = 0;
        fclose(f);
        parser(bytes);
        /* CHANGE: We allocated bytes, we free it */
        free(bytes);
        return 0;
}

void parser(char *bytes){
    char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "<title>");
    /* CHANGE: Make sure strstr found something */
    if (ptr) {
        /* Skip over the found string */
        ptr += 7:
        char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "</title>");
        if (ptr2) {
            /* Don't allocate buffer until we need it */
            /* Remember to leave space for the NUL */
            char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
            memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);
            /* null-terminate */
            output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;
            puts(output);
            free(output);
            parser(ptr2);
        }
    }
}
```

That's not the best code either. But it shows a few of the things you could think about.

Comment: Thank you for your code. It's really helpful. There's one problem though. The value of *ptr is null when I run the code.

Comment: And when I try to print bytes in main, only the first character of the file was copied.

Comment: @miguel: sorry, i just copied your code. The fread should be fread(bytes, 1, size, f). Read man fread and the code i wrote to understand why.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found out the problem too. It's working now.